# Custom input is not working in jQuery Token input plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

```
$("#responsible").tokenInput(
            [
                {id: 7, name: "a@gmail.com"},
                {id: 11, name: "b@gmail.com"},
                {id: 13, name: "c@gmail.com"},
                {id: 17, name: "d@gmail.com"},
                {id: 19, name: "e@yahoo.com"},
                {id: 23, name: "f@gmail.com"},
                {id: 29, name: "abc@gmail.com"},
                {id: 31, name: "ab@gmail.com"}
            ],{
                prePopulate: respArray,
                hintText: "Enter mailid",
                allowCustomEntry: true,
                theme : "facebook",
               noResultsText: "O noes",
                searchingText: "Searching...",
                minChars: 1,
                tokenLimit: 1,
                tokenValue: "name",
                preventDuplicates: true
            }
);
```

1. Token input is not working for custom entry. As soon as the cursor is out from the input, text will be disappeared from the input. How can i solve this problem.

Comment: For https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput 1.6.1 versio try allowFreeTagging: true option.

Answer (score 3):

Test with @Cindrella：

```
$("#responsible").tokenInput(
        [
            {id: 7, name: "a@gmail.com"},
            {id: 11, name: "b@gmail.com"},
            {id: 13, name: "c@gmail.com"},
            {id: 17, name: "d@gmail.com"},
            {id: 19, name: "e@yahoo.com"},
            {id: 23, name: "f@gmail.com"},
            {id: 29, name: "abc@gmail.com"},
            {id: 31, name: "ab@gmail.com"}
        ],{
            prePopulate: respArray,
            hintText: "Enter mailid",
            allowCustomEntry: true,
            theme : "facebook",
            noResultsText: "O noes",
            searchingText: "Searching...",
            minChars: 1,
            tokenLimit: 1,
            tokenValue: "name",
            allowFreeTagging: false,  // ！ADD THIS ！
            preventDuplicates: true
        }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#responsible").tokenInput(
  [
  {id: 7, name: "a@gmail.com"},
  {id: 11, name: "b@gmail.com"},
  {id: 13, name: "c@gmail.com"},
  {id: 17, name: "d@gmail.com"},
  {id: 19, name: "e@yahoo.com"},
  {id: 23, name: "f@gmail.com"},
  {id: 29, name: "abc@gmail.com"},
  {id: 31, name: "ab@gmail.com"}
  ],{
   prePopulate: respArray,
   hintText: "Enter mailid",
   allowFreeTagging: true,
   theme : "facebook",
   noResultsText: "O noes",
   searchingText: "Searching...",
   minChars: 1,
   tokenLimit: 1,
   tokenValue: "name",
   preventDuplicates: true
 }
 );
```

Include allowFreeTagging: true when you initiate.